# Subsetting data from a dataframe to remove specific rows

Tags: r, subset

```
#List of samples to reomove
samples_to_remove <- c("T_13C", "P3T", "GD3V", "DFRWE")

#Manually removing each sample individually
Data <- subset(Data, sample_name!="T_13C" & sample_name!="P3T"
                  & sample_name!= "GD3V"& sample_name!= "DFRWE")
```

I'm trying to remove a few specific rows from my dataframe (i.e the rows corresponding to the sample names in "samples_to_remove"). Is there a way that I can automate this (by iterating through the list of samples to remove?) instead of manually adding each condition into the subset function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

`Data <- Data[!(Data$sample_name %in% samples_to_remove), ]`